# Using async await in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await

Someone can say how to make such a construction work? Currently returns UnityExtension.
Well, or advise how easy it is to move a part of the non-MonoBehaviour code into a separate thread.

> UnityException: get_canAccess can only be called from the main thread. Constructors and field initializers will be executed from the loading thread when loading a scene. Don't use this function in the constructor or field initializers, instead move initialization code to the Awake or Start function.

```
    private async void Awake()
    {
        Mesh protoMesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
        SelfMesh = await InitMeshAsync(protoMesh);
    }

    protected async Task<CustomMesh> InitMeshAsync(Mesh protoMesh)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() => new CustomMesh(protoMesh.vertices, protoMesh.triangles));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the look at the exception, CustomMesh is using code that is not able to run form separate thread. `protoMesh.vertices, protoMesh.triangles` needs to be fetched before you start new thread.

```
private async void Awake()
{
    Mesh protoMesh = gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    SelfMesh = await InitMeshAsync(protoMesh);
}

protected async Task<CustomMesh> InitMeshAsync(Mesh protoMesh)
{
    var vertices = protoMesh.vertices;
    var triangles = protoMesh.triangles;
    return await Task.Run(() => new CustomMesh(vertices, triangles));
}
```

As what can be run from a separate thread and what not is tricky, and you need to constantly see how given field/method is implemented, but a good rule of thumb would be to always copy the requested field of a base type like `int`, `string`, `float[]` **before** you start another thread.

If you would go to the [GitHub](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/61f92bd79ae862c4465d35270f9d1d57befd1761/Runtime/Export/Graphics/Mesh.cs#L143) you would see that `vertices` uses `GetAllocArrayFromChannel` which uses `GetAllocArrayFromChannelImpl` which is native method whom cannot be used from separate thread.

Comment: Not sure if this was the problem. I also needed to remove the initialization of the class Color inside.